# Binary data over AWS Lambda triggered by API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I know there are several similar questions regarding this topic, but I haven't found my exact problem yet. If there is one, forgive me and please send me the link :-)

I have a lambda function that is triggered by API Gateway and returns a base64 encoded string of a image/tiff file.

I edited the API Gateway configurations so that it converts the string back to binary data.

If I test all this with the AWS functionality directly on, the binary image code (.tiff file) is correctly displayed.

[image: It works!]

However, if I test it via Postman, the downloaded file still contains the base64 encoded string and would need to be decoded. Thus, I cannot directly download the file from the API, but would have to do some conversion on the client side, right?

[image]

This is the header I receive from my API via Postman:
[image]

I included my `Accept` header as well: `image/tiff`

My python lambda backend return looks like this:
`return base64.b64encode(binary_data).decode('ascii')`

Why does it convert to binary data on the AWS console, but not via Postman (or curl)? I am a bit lost. Here my settings for the integration response:
[image]

In the end, I'd like to set all this via serverless, but I am already happy to get it to work via the web frontend and migrate to serverless later on.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What if you send `Accept: */*`?

Comment: Makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: API Gateway has always seemed fickle about how you should go about setting up the correct hidden magic involved for decoding binary content, though I'm sure it's my own lack of detailed understanding that makes it seem that way.

Comment: Enable the logs on your API Gateway, and set them to `info` level. Then you can see _exactly_ what is going on in Cloudwatch. A possible cause is that you're missing a header in Postman which API GW adds by default. Since the logs are truncated, I suggest you log in your lambda the headers of the request (simply `print` and look in Cloudwatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an direct answer to the question but more a workaround:

We solved this by generating a presigned url and displaying the binary data from there. That worked like a charm.